Encoding problem when redirecting standard output
A Python program writes ascii characters, Hungarian accented characters and EM DASH characters to the standard output simply using the print() function. If I redirect the output:
python test.py > out.txt
sometimes the outputfile is generated with Shift-JIS encoding. Without the redirection the output is always perfect.The redirected output is not always wrong, it depends somehow on the content. I am on Windows. Why can this happen? How can I avoid this? The following has been tried and it did not always help:
import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='utf-8')

I tried printing several texts, the EM DASH character seems to be one culprit but I am not sure.
EDIT: I have found the answer, actually the question is wrong. I inspected the produced text files with Notepad++ and the setting "Autodetect character encoding" was switched ON. Notepad++ decided that this particular file was encoded by Shift-JIS (he knows why). The files were always produced with Windows 1250, just Notepad++ played this little trick on me.
